# How to install Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) without composer

Tags: composer

I do not wish to use composer.
I wish to try out [Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)](https://www.drupal.org/project/amp) (in D8).
Is this possible and how do I do it?

Comment: What's blocking you from using composer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the AMP module requires the [Lullabot AMP Library](https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library), there really is not a great way to install this *without* Composer. That is because Composer will update the autoloader information with that namespace and vendor information and fetch dependencies. Downloading the tarball of the module and the GitHub download unfortunately will not do the trick - you must use Composer. The [module will block installation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/amp/tree/amp.install) if it cannot find the class namespace of `\Lullabot\Amp`.

The [Lullabot AMP Library](https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library) also has its own dependencies listed in its composer.json, so Composer is required here.

Comment: As I feared. Are there any other AMP Modules similar to it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Any module that has dependencies these days will basically require the usage of Composer - especially if those dependencies are external to Drupal like in this case, as there is no other way to manage them.